# How to clear Storage Key value in Selenium 4?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, devtools, selenium4

Selenium Webdriver 4.10.0

Using:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V114.Storage;
```

Code:

```
var devTools = Context.Driver as IDevTools;
        var session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();
        var command = new ClearDataForStorageKeyCommandSettings
        {
            StorageKey = "oidc.user:login:MyUI",
            StorageTypes = "SessionStorage"
        };
        var response = session.SendCommand<ClearDataForStorageKeyCommandSettings>(command);
```

On execution it throws an exception:

```
 System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Storage.clearDataForStorageKey: No valid storage type specified).
```

What storage it wants? I tried "session storage", "session", "session.storage" end nothing works.

Comment: I'd try "sessionStorage".   Might be easier to just execute javascript of sessionStorage.clear();